# Edit head information while using layout system laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, head

So for my website I have been using a layout structure in where each page pulls the main layout.

This contains header, and footer and all the stuff that goes in it, NAV, links, search bar etc.

This is also where all of the `<head></head>` info is located.

So my issue is:

I am trying to setup open graph sharing on my site but this requires specific info to be edited in the `<head>` section for each page.

However this seems impossible? Currently `layouts.main` calls:

```
@yield('content')
```

This is in the `<body>` of the document. then the `content` is yielded via the actual page contents shown below:

```
@extends('layouts.main') 

@section('content')

page stuff goes here, code, text, imgs 

@stop
```

My issue is that for open graph sharing and SEO I need to be able to edit each pages `<head>` info.

So what are my options? have no layout? leave the head open and close it in every single page? any ideas?

Comment: I don't fully understand the issue and I know nothing about SEO, but did you think about having a section in your `<head>`?

Comment: right the <head> section is only in the layout, and you cannot add things to <head> from the body

Comment: why do you need to add things *from the body*? can't you just create a section inside your `<head>` in your master layout, say you call it `@yield('seo')` and then in each of your pages you just do `@section('seo')`? That'll go straight to your `<head>`

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaand im retarted. Thank you dabadaba.